# Encountered illegal format of dynamic column string

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I am trying to use JSON in MariaDB. My table have two columns:

ID - INT. PK. Auto increment.

JsonText - BLOB

I have inserted Json into the blob column and it looks like so:

```
{
    "Fields" : {
        "CalPeriod" : "1",
        "CalYear" : "2014",
        "CompanyCode" : "E009",
        "CreditDebitInd" : "H",
        "FiscalYear" : "2014",
        "MaxPostDate" : "2014-01-14T00:00:00",
        "MinPostDate" : "2014-01-14T00:00:00"
    }
}
```

However, when I try to select the data and parse it back I get the error which I posted in the title.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_JSON(JsonText) FROM alliance.jsontest;
```

I don't understand. I even copied the code exactly from this website and it still threw the same error or it just returned the column with the word BLOB on it.

Answer (score 1):

*Better late than never...*

The function COLUMN_JSON is meant to be used with dynamics columns.
Inserting a json string into a blob column doesn't make it a dynamic column.

To insert data in this type of column, you need to use COLUMN_CREATE.
e.g.

```
INSERT INTO alliance.jsontest (JsonText)
VALUES (COLUMN_CREATE(
    "CalPeriod", "1", 
    "CalYear", "2014", 
    "CompanyCode", "E009", 
    "CreditDebitInd", "H", 
    "FiscalYear", "2014", 
    "MaxPostDate", "2014-01-14T00:00:00", 
    "MinPostDate", "2014-01-14T00:00:00"
));
```

Then you can use COLUMN_JSON or select one of the column by using COLUMN_GET.